# How to test secondary display?

Tags: java, android

I am using the following github code to run an android app on primary and secondary screen but I am unable to understand how to run secondary display using android emulator.
[source code](https://github.com/javajj/SecondaryDisplayAndroid)

Comment: Some phones have a "Simulate secondary displays" option in the developer settings menu. If yours doesn't, then you'll have to find one that does.